# Send a Facebook app notification from Node?

Tags: facebook, node.js

The Facebook [JavaScript API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) lets you send app notifications from your client-side app:

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: 'Test Request' })
```

...which results in an app notification:

[image]

How can I reproduce this behavior on the server side through Node?

(The [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) has no method to do this. I looked.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about Requests, and the documentation is [over in the Dialogs section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) (see also the [Request docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/)). If you get permission from the user to send Frictionless Requests, you can do this programmatically; otherwise, you have to show a request dialog (either via a popup for using a redirect).